# No Logcat print or notification from bootup receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver extending class named Bootup, which I would like to be called when the device first starts up after being shut down. I have implemented this into one of my other apps, so I migrated that code to this app and changed all the necessary details.

This is how it is registered under the application tag in the manifest XML file:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".reveivers.Bootup"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And this is the class itself:

```
public class Bootup extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Received when the phone boots up

        //Do some stuff

        //Test notification to check if it worked. Doesn't show, but the method is valid code.
        playNotification(context, "Active English", "Bootup received!");

        //More code, then this bit to check if it works again
        Log.d("test", milliseconds + " _ " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        //Yet more code
    }

    private void playNotification(Context context, String name, String description){
        long[] vibrate = new long[2];
        vibrate[0] = 500;
        vibrate[1] = 1000;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText(description)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationicon)
            .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 2000)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setContentTitle(name);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

}
```

I'll tell you now, all the code is valid. Yet for whatever reason, neither the logcat message nor the notification appears on the screen. The playNotification method has worked fine in the other application, so that isn't the issue.

Any ideas here?

EDIT: Added the code for the notification method, just in case it is of any use to anyone.

Comment: Have you launched the app at least once before testing?

Comment: Yes, the app launched right after I ran the code from AndroidStudio. I also just opened the app then rebooted just to make sure and,yet again, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission. Add this line in your manifest, outside the application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had this in the other application, I just skipped over it by accident when I was transferring things.